# How to choose which FaceTime number to call

Tags: ios, facetime

I have a friend with two iPhones, two different numbers.  When I call her with FaceTime audio, only phone A rings.  How can I call phone B?  The phones have two separate Apple ID addresses, but they are both set to receive Facetime calls on their 10 digit phone numbers.  I have both numbers listed in my contacts as 'Home' and 'Work' for the same person.

Comment: You would likely need to set up two separate contacts in order to call the second phone.

Comment: Still a pretty relevant question. Everyone can't duplicate all one's contacts just to be able to choose which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a standard way. It certainly isn't easy to find by using the Contacts or the Facetime app. But, it can be done:

1. Send a text message to the specific number you want to Facetime
   call.
2. Open the conversation thread.
3. Click "Contact" in the top right.
4. Click the symbol for calling.
5. Choose "FaceTime Audio".

Comment: Please see the edits I made to the question just now.

Comment: I didn't find a decent way either. When a contact has more than one phone number it looks like it is the first one in `Contacts` which is choosen.